# XSS: Break out of not-complete encoding

Tags: asp.net, security, xss

I'm pentesting the ASP.NET application running on Microsoft-IIS/7.5 web server and I'm sending it the following GET request parameters:

```
&search=aaa%20%*+,-/;<=>^|"'bbb
```

One of the parameters is search, where I've inputed the value that can be seen above. The value is printed in the returned response two times as follows:

The first parameter:

```
<input name="nn" type="text" value="aaa %* ,-/;&lt;=>^|&quot;&#39;bbb" class="cc" />
```

Quoted parameters in the first entry are as follows:

- "    ==> `&quot;`
- '    ==> `&#39;`
- <    ==> `&lt;`

I guess there's no way to break out of there, since the value is escaped and we can't input the " character right. Nevertheless, all parameters are not properly escaped, even though it's not possible to break out.

The second parameter:

```
<strong>aaa %* ,-/;<=>^|"'bbb</strong>
```

We can see that all of the characters are presented as they are, but there's a catch. After the < character there can't be any [a-zA-Z0-9] (maybe some other as well) characters, because we're probably getting blocked by the ASP.NET filters.

If we input the following:

```
&searchQuery=aaa<#script>alert('Hi');<#/script>bbb
```

We get the following output:

```
<strong>aaa<#script>alert('Hi');<#/script>bbb</strong>
```

I'm asking if you see any way to break out of the restrictions and execute arbitrary JavaScript code nevertheless?

THank you

Answer (score 0):

HTML requires the [tag name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-tag-name) to immediately follow the [start tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags) open delimiter `<`:

> **Start tags** must have the following format:
>
> 1. The first character of a start tag must be a U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN character (`<`).
> 2. The next few characters of a start tag must be the element's tag name.
>
> […]

Anything beyond that is up to a browser’s interpretation quirks.

But there are also other tags than element tags like markup declaration tags (`<!…>`), processing instruction tags (`<?…>`) and alternative comment tags (`<%…%>`)  that are recognized by certain browsers and allow certain hacks.

Have a look at the common XSS cheat sheets like [OWASP’s *XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet*](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) and the [*HTML5 Security Cheatsheet*](http://html5sec.org), or some HTML fuzzers like [Shazzer](http://shazzer.co.uk/).